# unrecognized selector sent to instance - trying to check a uilabel text value in a view

Tags: objective-c, ios

Up front, let me just say that I know the code I'll be showing below is probably inefficient, but I'm doing this "the hard way" because that's usually how I get things to stick when I'm learning...

I've created a class that I'm calling at runtime and within that is a label (I'll be adding more labels dynamically, etc.) When I check the container that will hold these views, I first check to see if there are any other views within it already. If not, I add the view directly. If there are other views already in there, I need to check that it won't put two of the same item in there. Since these are based on a single class, my current line of madness is to use the "headerLabel" outlet I've set up in the xib for this class. So...

In PhysicalExamDetailsNoteItem.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PhysicalExamDetailsNoteItem : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *headerLabel;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain)UILabel *headerLabel;

@end
```

In PhysicalExamDetailsNoteItem.m, I add: @synthesize headerLabel; after @implementation.

In ViewController.m:

```
#import "PhysicalExamDetailsNoteItem.h"

// ... And after a long list of code-based view setup, I call a method that includes the following ... //

            if([[physExamDetailsNoteItems subviews] count] > 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"More than one item already exists in the container, check preexisting items for %@ to eliminate duplication...", sender.currentTitle);
            for (PhysicalExamDetailsNoteItem *subview in [physExamDetailsNoteItems subviews]) {
                NSLog(@"subview.headerLabel.text = %@", subview.headerLabel.text);
                if (subview.headerLabel.text != sender.currentTitle) {
                    NSLog(@"%@ doesn't exist in the container, add it as a new item...", sender.currentTitle);
                    PhysicalExamDetailsNoteItem *noteItem;
                    noteItem = [[PhysicalExamDetailsNoteItem alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhysicalExamDetailsNoteItem" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                    [physExamDetailsNoteItems addSubview:noteItem.view];
                    noteItem.headerLabel.text = sender.currentTitle;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"No items exist in the container, add a new item...");
            PhysicalExamDetailsNoteItem *noteItem;
            noteItem = [[PhysicalExamDetailsNoteItem alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhysicalExamDetailsNoteItem" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            [physExamDetailsNoteItems addSubview:noteItem.view];
            noteItem.headerLabel.text = sender.currentTitle;                
        }
```

I'm getting the error at this section:

```
PhysicalExamDetailsNoteItem *subview in [physExamDetailsNoteItems subviews]) {
                NSLog(@"subview.headerLabel.text = %@", subview.headerLabel.text);
```

I have the headerLabel outlet rigged from the File's Owner object to the label view within IB, and when the enclosing method runs the if condition for the first time, it uses the else clause and populates my container view and changes the label text just as I want it to, but once it is called again and looks for the headerLabel for a comparison, it bails and I get:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView headerLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b17470'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm definitely open for alternatives to what I have built so far. I'm about a month into iOS dev at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are asking for all subviews, you are really getting all subviews.  Clearly one or more of them are not of the class you are looking for.  It's generally not safe to count on subviews of a given view to only be the views you have added yourself.

You should definitely change your fast enumeration declaration to use the UIView class as suggested by ennuikiller.  But the fix to your crash will be to test that a given subview is of the expected class before calling your method on it, like so:

```
for (UIView * subview in [physExamDetailsNoteItems subviews]) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[PhysicalExamDetailsNoteItem class]]) {
        PhysicalExamDetailsNoteItem * noteItem = (PhysicalExamDetailsNoteItem *)subview;
        NSLog(@"noteItem.headerLabel.text = %@", noteItem.headerLabel.text);
    }
}
```

This way, you'll use the dynamic runtime to ensure that the objects you're operating on are they type you expect.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. That got rid of the bailing and the errors, but I'm still missing something. When it checks for the kindOfClass, it returns false.

Comment: If all this setup is occurring in the same function, your codebase would be better served by doing your own tracking of which views have and have not been added, rather than using this second-pass system for auditing the views after the fact.  That is to say, if you can at all manage it, don't add these views in the first place if you're going to remove them later.

Comment: I'm not planning to remove them. I just want to make sure the same view isn't added twice. I would be more than happy to hear of an alternative. My biggest issue right now is that I'm now the "ios dev guru" on my team at work, with my credentials being that I can open xcode and have read half a book for beginners. I'm hacking my way through things at the moment for rapid prototyping so I was already confident that I may have gone down the "wrong" rabbit hole. :)

Comment: Ok.  So your best first option is to add logic to your code to explicitly ensure that the same view isn't added twice.  That is, have a BOOL flag or something in the function to indicate you've added it once.  This is the best choice because it is explicit and direct.  A second-best option might be to set the tag property of the view you are interested in to a particular number when you add it.  Then to determine later if you've added it already you can ask the superview for viewWithTag:, passing in your magic number.  If you haven't added it yet, that method will return nil.

Answer (score 0):

I think your need to declare the fast enumeration like so:

```
for (UIView *subview in [physExamDetailsNoteItems subviews]) {
```

and not as

```
PhysicalExamDetailsNoteItem *subview in [physExamDetailsNoteItems subviews])
```

After all you are processing UIView, not UIViewControllers.

Comment: Thanks, ennuikiller, but I tried that as an alternative and xcode flags any mention of subview.headerLabel.text as "Request for member 'headerLabel' in something not a structure or union".

Comment: I think the problem is that your class `PhysicalExamDetailsNoteItem` is a `UIViewController`, so there won't be any objects of your class in the `subviews` array, as that array only contains `UIView` (or `UIView` subclasses) objects. You can't find a `PhysicalExamDetailsNoteItem` the way you're trying to do.

Comment: Any suggestions on an alternative way to do this? I need to be able to add the note items dynamically and then be able to target them and their subviews. I'll be adding additional label views based on user interaction after they are added.